# Google Colab Not enough memory to open this page

Tags: google-chrome, google-colaboratory

I am training 5 CNN's with MNIST on Google Colab. Whenever I go to check on it to see if the program is done, the notebook becomes unresponsive. My computers memory max's out and the cpu spikes and then the webpage crashes and shows the "Not enough memory to open this page" error. Has anyone else had an issue like this?

Edit:
Link to notebook: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1EZ18Tf9RTwJB-Myy5YAK6py-SG_bNyDe

Comment: It will be difficult to diagnose this type of problem without more information. Can you share a notebook that reproduces the error?

Comment: Here's a link to the notebook: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1EZ18Tf9RTwJB-Myy5YAK6py-SG_bNyDe

Comment: I can't see the source for the Python file. But, my guess is that you need to limit your logging output. The volume is likely crashing your browser when attempting to render.

Answer (score 2):

You can organize your code in sections and then collapse the sections you’re not using at a given moment.  This significantly speeds up the notebook response in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

I was suffering from the same problem. I found a related post here [eddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnmachinelearning/comments/9guxix/google_colab_keeps_crashing_my_whole/). Did you print a lot of things during training? I was doing so, as said from the link, every print adds some kind of HTML thing to our browsers. Eventually, our pc crashes since it cannot take all those files due to memory limits.

I deleted my print lines, and it seems ok now.