# Google Colab Error: Buffered data was truncated after reaching the output size limit

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

**The Problem**

I am training a simple Artificial Neural Network (ANN) on Google Colaboratory and receiving an error message:

***"Buffered data was truncated after reaching the output size limit."***

This error message occurs at the final code block when GridSearch is called.

*Link to notebook:*  https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1TDYumLOoKA1VhrDlW38ztSbBPFmijIDz

This link contains the full code being run.

**Symptons**

I had first tried executing Step 1 (Importing Data) to Step 6 (Evaluating ANN) and the result was that Chrome crashed, presumably due to out of resources.  I researched and found a thread here regarding limiting output logging:

[Google Colab Not enough memory to open this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52667987/google-colab-not-enough-memory-to-open-this-page)

After Googling how to do this, I inserted "Step 0" in the notebook, which seemed to resolve Chrome crashing.

Training of the ANN now happens for several hours and reaches Step 6, where I receive the following output (please scroll right on the final line to see error):

```
Epoch 105/500
7200/7200 [==============================] - 0s 56us/step - loss: 0.4021 - acc: 0.8353
Epoch 106/500
7200/7200 [==============================] - 0s 59us/step - loss: 0.4019 - acc: 0.8351
Epoch 107/500
7200/7200 [==============================] - 0s 59us/step - loss: 0.4019 - acc: 0.8354
Epoch 108/500
7200/7200 [==============================] - 0s 58us/step - loss: 0.4019 - acc: 0.8347
Epoch 109/500
7200/7200 [==============================] - 0s 58us/step - loss: 0.4019 - acc: 0.8351
Epoch 110/500
1825/7200 [======>.......................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.3930 - acc: 0.8400Buffered data was truncated after reaching the output size limit.
```

**What have I tried?**

Apart from inserting Step 0, limiting output logging, I've tried searching on Google and StackOverflow but to no avail.  The only related thread is this:

[Buffered data was truncated after reaching the output size limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51463383/buffered-data-was-truncated-after-reaching-the-output-size-limit)

The author, however, has not responded and the single piece of advice given does not apply because training is on Google Colab and not local.  Therefore, "close the program and re-run it" doesn't really work, nor is it feasible that I keep closing and reopening an application multiple times.

Lastly, if Google Colab fails at training this simple ANN, how are we supposed to use it for anything else other than performing "Hello world"-type examples on Deep Learning?

**Conclusion**

I'm still stuck on limiting output size limit.  I don't need to see the entire output, preferably just the first 5 and last 5 lines or so...

Answer (score 2):

What terminates is the display of buffered data, that has to be displayed and not the computation itself, so it anyway doesn't affect your model, you can carry on with your model and proceed without worrying too much about this.

If you are skeptical of strangers on the internet and would like to verify that for yourself you can do this simple experiment.

You can limit the number of epochs and use multiple train statements, since you are using GridSearchCV, it will not retain the best hyperparamters across multiple runs, so you will have to handle that manually, you can use a list to store all hyperparameters and store their values, or you can create local optimums for each run and then among them select the global optimum, you can then compare this to the result you get the way you are running it now.

Limiting output logging or any other similar mechanism won't work, nor will restarting the notebook as the problem is not with what it computes, but what it displays. And if output buffer overflows, then the next time it has to display an output, it handles that automatically.